# Why isn't my IF statement applying to time?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I would like to get it to display 0 infront of the output if it's under 10.

```
const time = new Date();
let hour = today.getHours();
let minute = today.getMinutes();
let second = today.getSeconds();
if (second < 10) {
  second = 0 + second;
}

console.log(`Time is ${hour} : ${minute} : ${second}`);
```

Instead of showing for example 19:5:7, I would like to see 19:05:07

///
Ok, I found out what the problem was. 0 was a number not a string. Just started with JS.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: `'0' + second;`

Comment: Because `0 + second` is still `second`, since both are numbers.

Comment: When adding 0 + second you are adding two integers together. To add a 0 in front of the number you need to convert the expression to a string. To do this, you can simply add a string to the line such as `second = '' + 0 + second` or just do as j08691 suggested and do `second = '0' + second`.

Comment: Nina Scholz solution is also very elegant.

Comment: Thanks, everybody.

Answer (score 2):

You could pad the value with leading zeroes.

```js
const pad2 = s => s.toString().padStart(2, '0');

let today = new Date;
let hour = pad2(today.getHours());
let minute = pad2(today.getMinutes());
let second = pad2(today.getSeconds());

console.log(`Time is ${hour}:${minute}:${second}`);
```

Comment: For the OP, the first line is using an ES6 arrow function.